# Angularjs: $filter in controller returned data still tied to original object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, controller

I'm new to AngularJS and I decided I would start learning by trying to make a family tree app/SPA.
I hard-coded the data for the family tree, for testing purposes, into $scope.personRegister.
The first thing I want to do is to properly position all people/nodes from personRegister, loading them one generation at a time, using the ng-style directive.

I use the $filter inside the controller, to return only the people in generation 1000, and store the filtered results in a new object called test. 
I intend to then pass the data onto a method, outside of the app, to position the nodes.

The problem is, when I manipulate the data inside test, it also manipulates the original data inside $scope.personRegister, so that the also view gets updated.
Why does this happen?

```
<!-- borderbox is the subwindow -->
<div class="borderBox" style="left: 0px; top: 0px" ng-app="famTreeApp">

    <!-- the content of the borderbox -->
    <div class="insideContent" style="left: 100px; top: 0px">

        <div ng-controller="famTree">
            <div class="personBox" ng-repeat="name in personRegister"
            ng-style="{'left':name.posX+'px', 'top':name.posY+'px' }">
                {{name.fName}}
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

var familyTreeApp = angular.module("famTreeApp", []);

familyTreeApp.controller("famTree", function($scope, $filter, $log) {
//temp hard-coded data
$scope.personRegister = [
                           {id:1, genId:1000, gender:'M', fName:'John', momId:4, dadId:3,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },
                            {id:2, genId:1000, gender:'F', fName:'Lisa', momId:4, dadId:3,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },
                            {id:3, genId:999, gender:'M', fName:'Mark', momId:6, dadId:5,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },
                            {id:4, genId:999, gender:'F', fName:'Sarah', momId:8, dadId:7,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },
                            {id:5, genId:998, gender:'F', fName:'Martha', momId:0, dadId:0,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },
                            {id:6, genId:998, gender:'M', fName:'James', momId:0, dadId:0,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },
                            {id:7, genId:998, gender:'M', fName:'Frederick', momId:0, dadId:0,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },
                            {id:8, genId:998, gender:'F', fName:'Georgiana', momId:0, dadId:0,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },
                            {id:9, genId:1000, gender:'M', fName:'Trevor', momId:11, dadId:10,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },      
                            {id:10, genId:999, gender:'M', fName:'Andre', momId:8, dadId:7,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },
                            {id:11, genId:999, gender:'F', fName:'Teresa', momId:0, dadId:0,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' },
                            {id:12, genId:1000, gender:'F', fName:'Shakira', momId:4, dadId:3,  posX:'0',  posY:'0' }
];
$scope.spouseRegister = [
                            {husbandId:3, wifeId:4, haveKids:1, currMarried:1},
                            {husbandId:6, wifeId:5, haveKids:1, currMarried:0},
                            {husbandId:7, wifeId:8, haveKids:1, currMarried:1},
                            {husbandId:10, wifeId:11, haveKids:1, currMarried:1}
];
    $scope.test = $filter('filter')($scope.personRegister, {genId: 1000});

    $log.log($scope.personRegister[1]); //message to console


    $scope.test[1].posX = 50;
    $scope.test[0].fName += 'ny Boy';

    $log.log($scope.test[1]); //message to console
    $log.log($scope.personRegister[1]); //message to console

    //personPostioner(test);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kq8xduj6/2/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array contains objects which are the same objects referenced by `$scope.personRegister` and `$scope.test`. Yes, [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) returns a new array, but the contents of the array are still the same objects. If you want them to be different sets of data, filter off a copy of the original array.

```
$scope.test = $filter('filter')(angular.copy($scope.personRegister), {genId: 1000});
```

Comment: Awesome. Read the docs so many times, but I guess I missed that point. Thank You